# Get login URL on product page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I would like to get the `getLoginUrl()` url to put a button to login to my product detail view. Any idea how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone, this was the solution to get back to the referral page when logging in:

```
$url  = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
$login_url = $block->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => base64_encode($url)));
```

Comment: If I need this login button in a phtml file with the referrer link like this solution, then what will be the $this and $block, could you plz tell.

Answer (score 8):

You could do a direct call:

```
$this->getUrl('customer/account/login');
```

Please notice, when using this instead of the variant above, the customer will not be redirected to the previous page after logging in.

Answer (score 7):

Extend Product's block in your custom module's block file.

In your block's constructor inject object of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Url`. It should be something like

```
public function __construct(
    // some other code 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    // snip
) {
    $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
    // some other code
}
```

and function

```
public function getCustomerLoginUrl() {   
    return $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Now You can call `getCustomerLoginUrl()` function to get Login URL.

Check `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register` class for details.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about the phtml layer you could use:

```
<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/account/login')); ?>
```

Comment: how to get the referral URL?