# How to redirect to Magento2 Customer Login page from 3rd Party Application/External application.....?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to redirect to Magento2 Customer Login page from 3rd Party Application/External application. Suppose, when we want to redirect from any application to WordPress site
we write redirect to http://www.wordpress_site.com/wp-login.php

But I want to know, how we can redirect to Magento customer login page because Magento needs **referer**. which is where I didn’t understand, How can I pass referer from other application.

Example of Magento URL
[Get login URL on product page Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103292/get-login-url-on-product-page-magento-2)

Comment: You need to redirect your customers from external application to magento login page ? it Is what you are asking for ?

Comment: yes, you asked correctly.